# How would I use a South migration to load data into Django's auth_group table?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have some new groups that I'd like to add to Django's "auth_group" table and I'd prefer to use South to "migrate" that data into the database. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what steps I should take to create the migration file and then have it load my fixture.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The South docs have a [section about fixtures](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/fixtures.html) that includes this sample:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command("loaddata", "my_fixture.json")
```

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get that far. However, what model do you define in your fixture?  Thus far, I've tried "django.auth_group" and "auth_group".

Comment: I got it -- it's "auth.group".

Comment: This fails if you change the models after wards, e.g. migration 0002 loads fixture, migration 0003 adds new columns. When you try to run unit tests, 0002 fails because loaddata isn't using the historical model (as orm['some.model'].objects.create() would).